# Vertical cusp vertical tangent question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone help me solve the following two problems:

> - Does the following function have a *vertical  tangent* or *vertical cusp* at $c=0$
>
> $$f(x)=(3+x^{\frac{2}{5}})$$

I got for the derivative

$$f'(x)=\frac{2}{5\sqrt[5]{x}^3}$$

Now I think this would be a cusp because as x approaches zero from the left and right f(x) approches infinity.

> - My second question is with the function $f(x)=|{(x+8)^{1/3}}|$.

For my derivative I got

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}(x+8)^{\frac{-2}{3}},\;x > -8$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{3}(x+8)^{\frac{-2}{3}},\;x < -8$$

Would this not be a tangent because of the square expoent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your first function has a cusp at $x = 0$, because the derivative $f'(x)$ approaches $\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ and as $x\to 0^-$. We can see this at the point $(0, 3)$:

$\quad f(x)=\left(3+x^{\large\frac{2}{5}}\right)$ (see blue curve)

[image]

Your second function also has a cusp: at $x = -8$

Can you try to rewrite your derivative, or redefine if you mean "for $x \geq 0, f'(x) = ...$ and for $x < 0, f'(x) = ...?$.

$\quad f(x)=|(x+8)^{1/3}|$

[image]

Comment: +1 Why did you make the function apart to real and imaginary parts?

Comment: @Babak: Oh...that's just Wolfram's contribution, the blue is what matters here!

Comment: thanks for the help the weird thing is when I used WA it told me I had no cusp at all.

Comment: Did you maybe graph the derivative instead of the function?

Comment: sorry I meant greater than 8 or less than 8 in my second derivative.

Comment: that makes more sense!

Comment: @amwhy I  think I forgot to put in the absolute value when graphing. One question I have through is the second function a cusp because it is a piecewise function and therefore the right and left limits approach different infinity?

Comment: Yes, it is piecewise, discontinuous at $x = -8$